# How to get thing-at-point between separators

Tags: files, thing-at-point

I'm trying to get hold of the current filename at point. 
In an arbitrary buffer.

*Say I have list of files in a buffer and I want to be able to do something with each file. For that I need to determine filenames*

That's easy you may say, just use `(thing-at-point 'filename)`, and you'd be right, unfortunately that thing simply can't detect filenames with spaces in them.

So, here's the output of `ls`.
I turned whitespace-mode and saw this:

[image]

So I've figured - I need to hold onto the thing at point that separated by double whitespace at both ends. 
Or to be precise: `start-of-line|end-of-line|double-whitespace`

Can someone help me with that? Thanks!

*I looked into `previous-property-change` and `buffer-substring-no-properties`, but couldn't figure out how to apply for my thing, `re-search-forward` & `re-search-backward` is probably what I need to use, but I can't figure out the correct regex. Damn, regexes in elisp are wild and untamable.*

**update:** Attempting this:

```
(defun get-filename ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let* ((start (re-search-backward "\s\s\\|^"))
           (end (re-search-forward "\s\s\\|$")))
      (buffer-substring-no-properties start end))))
```

and it's not working ;(

**update 2:** This worked:

```
(defun get-filename ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((start (save-excursion (re-search-backward "\s\s\\|^")))
        (end (save-excursion (re-search-forward "\s\s\\|$"))))
    (string-trim
    (buffer-substring-no-properties start end))))
```

Comment: How is that list produced?

Comment: @wasamasa I don't think it's relevant to the question? It's simply output of `ls` in eshell

Comment: FWIW, to get a file name at point I recommend using `ffap-guesser` instead of `(thing-at-point 'filename)`.

Comment: Depending on how the list is produced, there may be a better way than guessing, like by side-stepping it and just retrieving the list as a data structure, not as a string.

Comment: @Drew this is awesome! I had no idea that exists! Thanks!

Comment: Although I just found out that `(ffap-file-at-point)` doesn't correctly deal with filenames with spaces.

Comment: If you want to capture spaces in a file name then you need some way to recognize the file-name beginning and end. `ffap-file-at-point` makes use of `ffap-alist` if it cannot otherwise find a file name. You can set this variable to contain an entry `(KEY . FUNCTION)` where `KEY` can be a regexp - then `FUNCTION` is invoked on the regexp match to produce the file name that gets returned. You might try that. Otherwise, you need to come up with some way to recognize the start and end, if `SPC` chars don't act that way.